# win32 ro win64 in the python output info?

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I have installed win7 ultimate 64, when I enter into python

```
d:\Python34\python
Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:25:23) [MSC 
v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

why the info is not the following:

```
 Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:25:23) [MSC 
 v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Windows 64-bit API is the almost entirely same as the Windows 32-bit API and both are referred to as Win32 for short. While there are a number of significant differences between the Windows 16-bit and 32-bit API, the 32-bit and 64-bit APIs can be used interchangeably.

The `64 bit (AMD64)` part of the version banner lets you know that you're using a 64-bit version of Python.